# Can a variable inherit elements of other variables?

Tags: global-variables

I'm using the term elements in my question generically to try to make my question easier to understand. I have this simple prompt to enter a name then print it.

```
prompt = "Enter a name: "
name = input(prompt)
print(f"\nHello, {name} ")
```

What I'm having trouble understanding is that if the '*prompt*' variable is equal to the statement "Enter a name:" why does it not also display the text in the print statement. Is the input function only accepting input from the user and negates the sentence which the variable is connected to. Thanks for helping me to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the input function only accepting input from the user and negates the sentence which the variable is connected to.

Yes, you are right.
`input(prompt)` only returns the data that the user entered, not the whole line.